# is it safe to access file using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
<output id="list"></output>

<script>
  function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object

    // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
      output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
                  f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                  f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
                  '</li>');
    }
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
  }

  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
</script>
```

I am to read a file using javascript but i don't know that would it be safe to access a file using javascript or not. if somebody know then please help me on this...

Comment: Well, it won't shoot you. Can you elaborate the question? What kind of threats are you expecting?

Comment: Considering that it can only be a file that you have saved to your own computer, you would be the best person to decide on its contents

Comment: What is the definition of "safe" used at OP? The `javascript` at Question does not actually read the `File` object contents, but rather, only the `.name`, `.type`, `.size`, or `.lastModifiedDate`  properties of the `File` object